# Firefox dont open with FirefoxDriver Selenium

Tags: java, maven, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run this code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.br/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

but it stops (the application dont exit, only stops) in the FirefoxDriver(), and no errors are thrown.
I'm using Firefox 25.0.1 (32 bit), Selenium IDE 2.5, java jdk 1.7, Windows 7 (64 bit) running with maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
  <version>2.0rc2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <type>jar</type>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a very outdated version of selenium.

Add a variable at the top of your project object model xml file, then use that as your selenium version.

```
<properties>
  <selenium.version>2.39.0</selenium.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
  <version>2.0rc2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <type>jar</type>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly! When I add the maven dependencies, he order in a strange way, for this I get the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of selenium is just too old for Firefox 25. It's currently at [2.39](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). 
Also normally you only need selenium-java and selenium-api and it's a good idea to keep their version consistent. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
  ...
  <properties>
    ...
    <selenium.version>2.39.0</selenium.version>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Kindly add below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Answer duplicated